# Local variable scope error - foreach loop

Tags: c#, foreach, scope

I have the following code:

```
if (Current == false)
{
    foreach (var visual in visuals)
        visual.IsSelected = value;
}

Visual visual = visuals[currentIndex];
```

And when I compile I have this error:

> A local variable named 'visual' cannot be declared in this scope
>   because it would give a different meaning to 'visual', which is
>   already used in a 'child' scope to denote something else

Also, if I don't declare the `visual` variable, that is I replace:

```
Visual visual = visuals[currentIndex];
```

with:

```
visual = visuals[currentIndex];
```

the error is the following:

> The name 'visual' does not exist in the current context

Why this behavior?

Comment: `which is already used in a` **child** `scope to denote something else` Since in your `foreach` loop has a variable called `visual`, that's why you get this error.

Comment: @SonerGönül the scope of the "first" visual is not limited inside the if statement?

Comment: Check out Eric Lippert's answer.. http://stackoverflow.com/a/2050864/447156

Comment: It is by design of C#. It reduces ambiguity. 
Similar [question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059210/using-a-variable-name-used-in-a-child-scope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case there is ambiguity between the variables declared outside and inside.(global and local).

The compiler is confused as to what `visual` you are referring to. The outer one or inner one?

And in the second case, the compiler does not know what is `visual`.

Read more about it [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691132%28v=vs.71%29.aspx);

Answer (score 1):

> Why this behavior?

in your first case you have already declared the variable with name `visual` in your foreach loop.

in your second case you can not use the keyword `visual` because it does not exist. it is only available within your foreach loop.

Try This:

```
Visual visual1 = visuals[currentIndex];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
   if (Current == false)
    {
        foreach (var visual in visuals)
            visual.IsSelected = value;
    }

   // Parent and child scope have same variable name so it creates ambiguity.
    Visual visual = visuals[currentIndex];
```

and

```
if (Current == false)
    {
        foreach (var visual in visuals)
            visual.IsSelected = value;
    }

   // The variable visual in not defined outside the scope of if statement
    visual = visuals[currentIndex];
```

Answer (score 1):

As Soner Gönül points out, the first construct:

```
if (Current == false)
{
    foreach (var visual in visuals)
        visual.IsSelected = value;
}

Visual visual = visuals[currentIndex];
```

is illegal by definition of the language.  See the link that Soner provided:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2050864/447156

Making this illegal reduces the chance of confusion when humans read the code.  The compiler could treat this as legal, but the designers of the language felt (and I agree) that this was an opportunity to make C# easier to understand.